# How can I save many copy of imageview in gallery

Tags: android, android-studio, imageview, save

I am saving my `imageview` to gallery but when i save another `imageview` it will replace the previous one and I don't know why is the `file.createNewFile();` is ignored. How can I save different image file for my `imageview` ? Codes below.

```
    save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            RelativeLayout content = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.dashBoard);
            content.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
            Bitmap bitmap = content.getDrawingCache();
            File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()+ imagename+ ".png");

            try {
                if (!file.exists()) {
                    file.createNewFile();

                }
                FileOutputStream ostream = new FileOutputStream(file);
                bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 10, ostream);
                ostream.close();
                content.invalidate();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "SAVED", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();

            } finally {
                content.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `UUID.randomUUID()` instead of `imagename`
i think that the imagename is always the same , that's why it replace the old one

Comment: thank you for the answer. it works now and I understand now what is my problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can take current time as file name::

```
    save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        RelativeLayout content = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.dashBoard);
        content.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
        Bitmap bitmap = content.getDrawingCache();
        Date d = new Date();
        CharSequence imagename  = DateFormat.format("MM-dd-yy hh-mm-ss", d.getTime());
        File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()+ imagename+ ".png");

        try {
            if (!file.exists()) {
                file.createNewFile();

            }
            FileOutputStream ostream = new FileOutputStream(file);
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 10, ostream);
            ostream.close();
            content.invalidate();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "SAVED", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();

        } finally {
            content.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
        }
    }
});
```